# Why am getting a runtime(SIGABRT) error in SPOJ when my code works just fine?

Tags: c++

It's been almost three days and i can't figure out where the error is. I would be grateful if anyone of you would help me figuring it out.
The question is to find a palindrome number greater than the given test cases, where the first line is the number of test cases followed by the test cases themselves.

I have already tried to debug it, but it's still not working.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string reverse(string x) {
  reverse(x.begin(), x.end());
  return x;
}

int main() {
  int x, len, temp;
  cin >> x;
  string arr[x], cop1;
  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    cin >> arr[i];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    len = arr[i].length();
    cop1 = arr[i];

    if (len % 2 == 0) {
      cop1 = arr[i].substr(0, len / 2) + reverse(arr[i]).substr(len / 2);
      if (cop1 == reverse(cop1) && cop1 > arr[i]) {

      } else {
        temp = stoi(arr[i].substr(0, len / 2)) + 1;
        cop1 = to_string(temp) + reverse(to_string(temp)).substr(0);
      }
    } else {

      cop1 =
          arr[i].substr(0, len / 2 + 1) + reverse(arr[i]).substr(len / 2 + 1);
      if (cop1 == reverse(cop1) && cop1 > arr[i]) {

      } else {
        temp = stoi(arr[i].substr(0, len / 2 + 1)) + 1;
        cop1 = to_string(temp) + reverse(to_string(temp)).substr(1);
      }
    }
    arr[i] = cop1;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I'm gtting runtime error SIGABRT in this code

EDIT:

This is the new code that i tried..but I am getting the same error..while in Dev C++ it's running fine

```
 #include <string>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <vector>

 using namespace std;
 int temp=0;
 string reverse(string x)
 {
     reverse(x.begin(),x.end());
     return x;
 }
 string even(string y)
 {
     string cop=y;
     string cop1=y;
     cop1=cop.substr(0,y.length()/2)+reverse(cop).substr(y.length()/2);
     if(cop1==reverse(cop1)&&cop1>cop)
 {
     return cop1;    
 }
 else
 {
     temp=stoi(cop.substr(0,y.length()/2))+1;
     cop1=to_string(temp)+reverse(to_string(temp)).substr(0);
 }
 return cop1;    
 }
 string odd(string z)
 {
     string cop1=z;
     string cop=z;
     cop1=cop.substr(0,z.length()/2+1)+reverse(cop).substr(z.length()/2+1);
     if(cop1==reverse(cop1)&&cop1>cop)
     {
         return cop1;        
     }
     else
     {
         temp=stoi(cop.substr(0,z.length()/2+1))+1;
         cop1=to_string(temp)+reverse(to_string(temp)).substr(1);
         return cop1;
     }           
 }
 int main()
 {
     int x,len,temp;
     cin>>x;
     vector<string> arr;
     string input;
     for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
     {
         cin>>input;
         len=input.length();
         if(len%2==0)
         {   
             arr.push_back(even(input));
         }
         else
         {
             arr.push_back(odd(input));
         }
     }
     for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
     cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
     getch();
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Most likely it's sent due to timeout on SPOJ.

Comment: Fyi, `string arr[x]` - don't do that. use a proper vector. VLAs aren't part o the C++ standard.

Comment: Logic would suggest, if your program is receiving a `SIGABRT` signal, that your code does not work "just fine".   Under most unix flavours, a program receives a `SIGABRT` signal when some library code it is executing decides something is wrong and calls `abort()`.   Cases where that happens include an internal error in a library when you pass it invalid data.    Incidentally, `cin>>x; string arr[x]` (using a variable length array) is not valid C++

Comment: `string arr[x]` -- Make `x` a large number, and your stack gets blown to bits.  Please use `std::vector<std::string> arr(x);` instead.

Comment: Your `temp` is uninitialized, as you never reset / set it to a value.  It can potentially be either a junk number, or an artifact from a previous test.  This is why writing functions is the way you should be doing this, instead of dumping an entire code inside of `main`.  If you wrote a function, and have `temp` be a local inside that function, then this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You can avoid the non-standard variable-length array by solving one test case at a time instead of gathering them into an array first. It also simplifies the rest of the code.

Comment: just try to invent more test data and you will reproduce this issue. Link to the problem would help you to invent those test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Program is getting `std::invalid_argument` exception in `stoi` as conversion was not possible/success.

[stol Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)

Please check your input to `stoi` it will resolve issue hopefully.

> If it doesn't work. Please share your console input/output with SIGABRT. If possible GDB log can also help.

I hope it helps!